# Подсчет нулей в введенном аргументе

Tags: javascript, математика

Хочу подсчитать количество нулей которые повстречаются, если посчитать от единицы до введенного числа. Например если ввести число 20, то ответ должен быть 2 (по нулю в каждом числе 10 и 20), для 101 ответ 12. Для этого написал такую функцию:

```js
function countZeros(n) {
    if ((n ^ 0)!==n || n<0 || isNaN(n)===true) {
        return false;
    }
    
    let result = 0;   // Результат
    let rank = 1;   // Номер разряда (начинаем с младших)
    let low = 0;   // Число в младших разрядах (изначально равно 0)
    let high = n;  // Число в старших разрядах (изначально равно n)
    
    for (high /= 10; high >= 1;) {
        
        if (high % 10 !== 0) {
            result += Math.floor(((high - 1) * rank) + (low + 1));
        }
        else {
            result += Math.floor(high * rank);
        }
        
        low += rank * (n % 10);  // Увеличиваем число в младших разрядах
        rank *= 10;           // Переходим к следующему разряду
        high /= 10;        // Уменьшаем число в старших разрядах
    }
    return result;
```

Но она считает правильно только если ввести цифры до 109 включительно.
Пробовал еще такой вариант:

```js
let counterZeroes = 0;
    for (i = 10; n/i >= 1; i *= 10) {
        counterZeroes += Math.floor(n/i);
    }
    return counterZeroes;
```

Но такая функция считает правильно только до 100.

Answer (score 2):

Однострочно можно и через строку пойти

```
function countZeros(num) {
    return (num + '').split('').reduce((x, y) => x + (y === '0'), 0);
}
```

Comment: Условие задачки изменилось*)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function countZeros(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
    
  var r = 0;

  if (n > 9) 
    r = countZeros(n - 1);
  while (n > 0) {
    if (n % 10 == 0)
      r++;
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  }
  return r;
}

console.log(countZeros(20));
console.log(countZeros(102));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но ваш код тоже не работает. Может я не правильно сформулировал вопрос. Например если ввести цифру 20, то ответ должен быть 2 (по одному нулю в числах 10 и 20, получится 2 нуля). В цифре 101 ответ должен быть 12.

Comment: @lonecatkz да, неправильно сформулировали.

Answer (score 1):

Решение грубым перебором, для каждого отдельного числа считает ноли.

Для 10,000,000 в хроме-75 выполняется около за 4 секунды)

```js
console.log( countZeros(20) );
console.log( countZeros(102) );
console.log( countZeros(1000) );

function countZeros(x){
  let zeros = 0;
  for( let i = 10; i <= x; i++ ){
    zeros += getZeros(i);
  }
  return zeros;
}

function getZeros(x){
  return (("" + x).match(/0/g)||[]).length;
}
```

Но ждите, пока кто-то даст ответ с красивой математикой)) Я попробовал найти закономерность - сдался)

Answer (score 0):

```
function countZeros(n) {
    let sum=0
    for (let i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        `${i}`.split('').forEach(element => {
           if( element.includes('0')){
            sum +=1
           }
        });
    }
    return sum
}
countZeros(20); // 2 – два нуля, по одному в числах 10 и 20
countZeros(100); // 11 – 11 нулей в числах: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100
```

Я вот так решил,делаю из числа i массив и перебираю каждое его значение, проверяя содержит ли оно 0. Если да прибавляю 1 к переменной sum.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function countZeros(n) {
    if (typeof (n) !== 'number' || n < 0) {
        console.log('Пожалуйста, введите положительное число');
        return;
    }
    let result = 0;
    if (n < 10) return result;
    for (let i = 10; i <= n; i += 10) {
        result++;
        if (i % 100 === 0) {
            for (let k = i; k < i + 10 && k <= n; k++) {
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // в частности, например, опишите, чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается от предыдущих.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть функция `f`: `f(n)` - общее число нулей в десятичной записи чисел из диапазона `[1, n)`.

Функция `g`: `g(n)` - число нулей в десятичной записи числа `n`.

Связь между `f` и `g`:

```
f(n) = sum(g(i) | i in [1, n - 1])
```

Свойства `g`:

```
g(10n) = g(n) + 1
g(10n + k) = g(n), если 0 < k < 10
```

Суммируем

```
sum(g(10n + k) | k in [0, 9]) = 1 + 10 * g(n)
```

Следовательно

```
f(10n) = sum(g(i) | i in [1, 10n - 1]) =
= sum(g(i) | i in [1, 9]) + sum(g(i) | i in [10, 10n - 1]) =
= 0 + sum(sum(g(10j + k) | k in [0, 9]) | j in [1, n - 1]) = 
= sum(1 + 10 * g(j) | j in [1, n - 1]) =
= n - 1 + 10 * sum(g(j) | j in [1, n - 1]) = n - 1 + f(n)
```

Добавим краевое условие и ещё одно тривиальное:

```
f(n) = 0, если n < 10
f(n) = f(n - 1) + g(n - 1)
```

Можно программировать:

```js
const g = n => (n.toString().match(/0/g) || []).length;

const f = n => {
    if (n < 10) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n % 10 > 0) {
        return f(n - 1) + g(n - 1);
    }
    const m = n / 10;
    return 10 * f(m) + m - 1;
};

const countZeros = s => f(s + 1);

for (let p = 0; p < 16; ++p) {
    const n = 10 ** p;
    console.log(p, n, countZeros(n));
}
```

Время работы пропорционально длине числа.